# How to choose only two years in R using lubridate (not including years in between)

Tags: r, lubridate

I am using RStudio and a semi-large data set in which I want to only select the years 2016 and 2023 in the data set in the column observation_date. I tried using the lubridate to do this. However, I have only found how to select in between the two years and even then I got an error and it does a range rather than the two years themselves. Also in the data set 2016 and 2023 end at different times as the data for 2023 ends in October. I would appreciate any help as I am new at this.

I have listed below my first code chunk that I have so far. I will attach  a screenshot of what the column looks like. Unfortunately I am unable to attach the full data. [Here is what the column looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kaqz.png)
Here is what my code looks like so far:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfvJH.png)

Also here is what the error looks like:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)`.
Caused by error in `as.character()`:
! cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
Backtrace:

1. BudburstObs %>% mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) %>% ...
2. lubridate::dmy(Date)
3. lubridate:::.parse_xxx(...)
4. base::lapply(list(...), .num_to_date)
5. lubridate (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
   Error in mutate(., Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) :
   Caused by error in `as.character()`:
   ! cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) %>%
  filter(Date >= as.Date('01-01-2016') & Date <= as.Date('2023-10-31'))
select()

BudburstObs$observation_date_NEW <- mdy(BudburstObs$observation_date)
str(BudburstObs)
```

I tried looking through lubridate for a way to select two years only and have not figured it out. I have found out how to do a range but that is not what I would like. I am also getting an error.

Comment: In the posted image the column name is `observation_date`, not `Date`. Also, images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code:

1. it is not `dmy(Date)`, in your case it is `mdy(Date)`
2. In your code you try to filter Date between 2016 and 2023 and not only 2016 and 2023 as you state in your intro.

Here is an adapted code (not tested):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) %>% 
  filter(year(Date) == 2016  | year(Date) == 2023) # year is from lubridate
```